# How to get date formating in AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, I am using location.search() to get date field from URL passed through in param myDates as below

```
$scope.myDates= $location.search()['myDates'];
```

However, it works only if it is in the format 
**`MMMM-DD-YYYY`**

I need it to be in the format DD-MMMM-YYYY as in 20-12-2010 etc.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat date as date, the first thing would be to convert the querystring date into a `Date` data type using

`$scope.myDates=Date.parse($location.search()['myDates']);`

As this MDN documentation says about this method, the input format of string should be

> A string representing an RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date.

Once you have converted it into date you can do any manipulation and formatting using `Date` object `toString()` method or `$date` filter in AnuglarJS